# Two possible definitions of a catenary topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

$\def\codim{\operatorname{codim}}$Let $X$ be a topological space and consider the following two properties that $X$ might have:

1. For every pair of irreducible subsets $T\subset T'$ we have $\codim(T,T')<+\infty$ (see [02I3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02I3) for the definition of the codimension) and every maximal chain of irreducible closed subsets
   $$
   T=T_0\subset T_1\subset\cdots\subset T_e=T'
   $$
   has the same length (equal to $\codim(T,T')$).
2. For every pair of irreducible closed subsets $T\subset T'$ there exists a maximal finite chain of irreducible closed subsets
   $$
   T=T_0\subset T_1\subset\cdots\subset T_e=T'
   $$
   and every such chain has the same length.

The first property is the definition of catenary space in the SP, [02I1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02I1). The second property is how the notion appears defined in the first paragraph of Section [02IV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02IV).

It is clear that 1$\Rightarrow$2. But is the converse true as well?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\codim{\operatorname{codim}}$The answer is yes. Here's the proof: Suppose $X$ satisfies 2. We must show that $\codim(T,T')<+\infty$ for every pair of irreducible closed subsets $T\subset T'$. For the sake of looking for a contradiction, suppose $\codim(T,T')=+\infty$ for some irreducible closed subsets $T\subset T'$.

Let $e$ be the length of all maximal finite chains between $T$ and $T'$. Since $\codim(T,T')=+\infty$, there is a chain
$$
\label{1}\tag{1}
T=T_0\subset T_1\subset\cdots\subset T_n= T'
$$
of irreducible closed subsets with $n>e$. This chain cannot be maximal. However, we can enlarge it to a maximal one by taking, for each $i\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, a maximal finite chain between $T_i$ and $T_{i+1}$ and inserting it into \eqref{1}. A contradiction.